# Angular testing - test.ts not found

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, testing, jasmine

I'm trying to follow the official Angular docs to set up testing for an Angular project - https://angular.io/guide/testing#service-tests

I've downloaded the sample Angular project from the page above, using the first (top) link. I've done an `npm install` and when I run `ng serve` it builds fine.

When I run `ng test` using the CLI, I get the message:

```
ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Cant' resolve 'C:Code\testing\src\test.ts' in 'C:\Code\testing'

ERROR in error TS6053: File 'C:Code\testing\src\test.ts' not found.
```

I looked at this question - [How to resolve test.ts when running ng test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46282174/how-to-resolve-test-ts-when-running-ng-test), but in that case the file actually exists, but in the Angular example project it doesn't exist at all.

(When I first ran `ng test` I originally got a message about Jasmine Marbles being missing, which I resolved using:)

```
npm install jasmine-marbles --save
```

The documentation says:

> You can fine-tune many options by editing the karma.conf.js and the
>   test.ts files in the src/ folder.

So I know the test.cs is some kind of configuration file, but how do I generate it? It doesn't exist in the Angular 'live example' project either. And how do I know that a test.cs I generate will work reliably with this project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know whether you can generate just the test.ts file or not, but as far as i know this file is automatically generated when you create a new angular project using angular-cli. So you can just create a new project using angular-cli then copy the src/test.ts file from that new project

Answer (score 4):

I used @joshbaeha's suggestion to `ng new` a new Angular 5 project and copied the `test.ts` file, which appears to be completely generic and not reliant on project structure or anything else. Everything is now working. Here it is:

### test.ts

```
// This file is required by karma.conf.js and loads recursively all the .spec and framework files

import 'zone.js/dist/zone-testing';
import { getTestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import {
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting
} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';

declare const require: any;

// First, initialize the Angular testing environment.
getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting()
);
// Then we find all the tests.
const context = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
// And load the modules.
context.keys().map(context);
```